# Rewrite Logic, is there a better way to do this?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, vhosts

I'm curious, is there a more efficient way to do the the following? Right now it works great, just seems like overkill...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.clientcollabhq\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.clientcollabhq\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?subdomain=%2&kohana_uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the common conditions in the inverted form as condition for a break/skip rule:

```
# stop processing if one of these conditions are fulfilled
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.clientcollabhq\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.clientcollabhq\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?subdomain=%2&kohana_uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Now every request that matches one of these conditions will make this rule being applies and thus end the rewriting process.